# emacs goodies in windows

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

I got emacs in windows 8. I used the `tabbar` mode in ubuntu which came with `emacs-goodies-el` package. How and where do I install `emacs-goodies-el` in windows?

Answer (score 1):

The package only exists in Debian. Its copyright file in /usr/share/doc/emacs-goodies-el indicates where the included modules were obtained.

Even simpler, though, is to simply google for tabbar. I'll spare you the effort, though; the top hit is http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode

See also http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Tabbar which is a lot more focused.